# Node Redis does not work on my windows computer even though the server is up and running

Tags: node.js, windows, redis, node-redis

```
const express = require("express");
const redis = require("redis");
const app = express();

const client = redis.createClient({
  url: "redis://admin123@ec2-35-182-15-126.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
});

client.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("redis connected");
  console.log(`connected ${redisClient.connected}`);
});

client.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Node server started");
});
```

The above code does not show any connection to redis server even though I have checked the EC2 redis instance by connecting using Redsmin.
[hosting details in Redsmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZvwk.png)

This is a very simple thing to do but the error that I get cannot be googled.

> > Node server started C:\Users\Sithira_105661\Desktop\Projects\Learning\Redis\node_modules@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:387
> > return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
> > ^
>
> ClientClosedError: The client is closed
> at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (C:\Users\Sithira_105661\Desktop\Projects\Learning\Redis\node_modules@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:387:31)
> at Commander.commandsExecutor (C:\Users\Sithira_105661\Desktop\Projects\Learning\Redis\node_modules@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:160:154)
> at Commander.BaseClass. [as set] (C:\Users\Sithira_105661\Desktop\Projects\Learning\Redis\node_modules@node-redis\client\dist\lib\commander.js:8:29)
> at Object. (C:\Users\Sithira_105661\Desktop\Projects\Learning\Redis\redis.js:19:8)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Help me understand the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you first make sure that the server is reachable with the following CLI cmd: `redis-cli -u redis://<url>`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

finally found the solution. I used node-redis 3.0.0 rather than 4 and the code works fine. I do not know why it does not work in latest node-redis . If any of you guys are getting this issue use node-redis 3

Comment: thank you bro. I was struggling for 3 days and I was about to go crazy. Even though I did everything completely right, it just wasn't working. and finally "npm i redis@3.1.2" its workkkkk

Comment: Your welcome. I was also struggling with this but luckily stumbled upon the solution.

Comment: Almost pulled my hair out, thanks so much

Comment: Major version "3" is not supporting the Hash commands

Comment: Damn you save my life and this redis so painful don't tell us any thing.

Answer (score 10):

I used node-redis 3.1.2 rather than 4 and the code works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I don't thing we should decrease the version from 4 to 3.

we can use -

```js
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient();

   
(async () => {
    await client.connect();
})();

client.on('connect', () => console.log('Redis Client Connected'));
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Connection Error', err));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check your ec2 redis connection

```
    const client = redis.createClient({
       url: "redis://username:password@ec2_endpoint:port",
     });
```

Connection string format: `redis[s]://[[username][:password]@][host][:port]`

Answer (score 2):

You are using a very old version of Redis, an abandoned project by Microsoft called OpenTech Redis.

I suggest you checkout Memurai.
Memurai is an up-to-date native Windows port of Redis that derives from that project (see [this commit](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/commit/287e01c68ce9ec6e7a739c19b04b1dfc253326e3)).

Memurai is also available with a free Developer Edition.

Disclaimer: I work in Memurai.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using redis ^4.0.0, you can do this:

```
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const { REDIS_HOST_URL } = require('../config');

const client = createClient({ url: REDIS_HOST_URL });

(async () => {
    await client.connect();
})();

client.on('connect', () => console.log('::> Redis Client Connected'));
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('<:: Redis Client Error', err));
```

You can read more on their documentation [here](https://redis.js.org/#node-redis-usage-basic-example).

Answer (score 1):

In version 4.0.1, we have to add .connect() to run redis.

They have [migration guide](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/v3-to-v4.md)

This is my code, but it seems to not work well.

```
async function connectRedis(){

    try {

        const redisURL = '<link-redis-provider>';

        const client = createClient({
           url: redisURL
        });

        await client.connect();
        console.log('Cache is ready');

    } catch (error) {
       console.log('Connect to cache is failed')
    }
}
module.exports = {connectRedis}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to Version
3.1.2

1. remove node_modules and package-lock
2. open package.json
3. edit redis to version 3.1.2 and save it
4. run npm install

if you just want to install direct :

```
npm i redis@3.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: '<hostname>',
    port: <port>,
    password: '<password>'
});

client.on('error', err => {
    console.log('Error ' + err);
});
```

you can read detail at here
https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue may be due to v4+ using typescript in source code. if your server code is not typescript compatible. could be the issue .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience. I attributed the cause of the issue with the redis server I am using which is older than 5.0. So, perhaps you are in a similar situation.

According to the [node-redis documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VJTb.png),

"Node Redis should work with older versions of Redis, but it is not fully tested and we cannot offer support." However, "< 5.0" is marked not supported.

Answer (score 0):

install the redis client 3.1.2
just put 3.1.2 in dependencies in package.json next to redis

"dependencies" : {
"redis": "3.1.2"
}

Answer (score 0):

Most of the previous answers point in the correct direction. However, one minor change which caused me an hour to figure out was semi-colon and parenthesis.

*Error:*

```
(async () => { client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err)); })
    ^
    
TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
```

It was happening due to change in *redis* package of nodejs. From `4.x.x` versions, the API to connect database has significantly changed.

The correct syntax now is:

```
(async () => { client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err)); })();
```

Inside immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) require parenthesis to invoke them.

PS: `async` and `await` are necessary as Node Redis now uses native Promises by default for all functions.

Documentation: https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/v3-to-v4.md